# Appending an int array to a string in c:

Tags: c, c-strings

I'm trying to append an array of integers into a string, basically I'm trying to get it into the following format: A :123456   where A is a character, given by a parameter, and 123456 is an integer array. I'm getting a **bus error** when running code, and I've done a search on here, and on google for the correct way to do something similar to what I have been hoping to achieve, but the examples don't directly relate to this so I was wondering if I could get some help. Thanks in advance

```
char *print_cards_played(Player *player) {
    char *result = "";
    int i = 0;

    result += sprintf(result, "%c :", player->playerID);

    while(player->cardsPlayed[i] != 0) {
        result += sprintf(result, "%d", player->cardsPlayed[i]);
        i++;
    }

    result += sprintf(result, "\n");

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Uh, uh, C strings are not python strings. You cannot concatenate strings in C with the `+` operator. If you just want to print (your function name suggests that), don't build a string first, just print what you want, piece by piece.

Comment: Don't try to learn C by guessing and playing a little around with your code. It won't work. So many silly things are perfectly valid C code but do things you totally haven't expected. And many constructs are undefined but the compiler won't tell you (and it often can't). Read the documentation of the functions you use. And read about memory allocation, you shouldn't return addresses of local variables.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "append" to a string defined by:

```
char *result = "";
```

All that gives you is a pointer named `result` which points at a single read-only location in memory where the character `'\0'` (the string terminator) is stored. You can't write to it.

You need to have an actual buffer of some suitable size:

```
char *result = malloc(128);
```

If that allocation succceeds, you have what is called a "heap buffer" which will stay around even if the function that did the allocation exits. You can safely `return` this pointer, unlike a local array which would disappear as the function exited.

Then you can use `sprintf()`, but of course not with `+=`, you can't add strings in C. The best solution might be to `sprintf()` to a temporary small string, then `strcat()` that string onto the `result`. You can keep track of the appended length to make it fast, but that's not critical for small problems on a modern machine.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
char *print_cards_played(Player *player) {
    char result[128];// = "";
    char *p = result;
    int i = 0;

    p += sprintf(p, "%c :", player->playerID);

    while(player->cardsPlayed[i] != 0) {
        p += sprintf(p, "%d", player->cardsPlayed[i]);
        i++;
    }

    p += sprintf(p, "\n");

    return strdup(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own function and model it on the `snprintf` paradigm, which takes a buffer and its length and fills that buffer with the desired string. If the buffer is too small, the string will be truncated, but still be a valid, null-terminated string:

```
int str_cards_played(char *buf, int nbuf, const Player *player)
{
    int n;
    int i = 0;

    n = snprintf(buf, nbuf, "%c: ", player->playerID);

    while(n < nbuf && player->cardsPlayed[i] != 0) {
        n += snprintf(buf + n, nbuf - n, "%d", player->cardsPlayed[i]);
        i++;
    }

    if (n < nbuf) n += snprintf(buf + n, nbuf - n, "\n");
    return n;
}
```

You'd call the function like so:

```
char buf[20];

str_cards_played(buf, sizeof(buf), player);
printf("'%s'\n", buf);
```

If the allocation is on the stack like here, you don't have to worry about memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Bus error is because of: `char *p = "String Literal";`

The reason stated clearly in c-faq as,

> Anywhere else, it turns into an unnamed, static array of characters, and this unnamed array may be stored in read-only memory, and which therefore cannot necessarily be modified. In an expression context, the array is converted at once to a pointer, as usual, so the second declaration initializes p to point to the unnamed array's first element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcatInt` described below, to concat char* and int

```
char* itoa(int i, char b[]){
    char const digit[] = "0123456789";
    char* p = b;
    if(i < 0){
        *p++ = '-';
        i *= -1;
    }
    int shifter = i;
    do{ //Move to where representation ends
        ++p;
        shifter = shifter/10;
    } while(shifter);
    *p = '\0';
    do{ //Move back, inserting digits as u go
        *--p = digit[i%10];
        i = i/10;
    } while(i);
    return b;
}

char* strCatInt(char* str, int num) {
    char numStr[10];
    itoa(num, numStr);
    return strcat(str, numStr);
}
```